# C# SSL соединение xNet, WebRequest

Tags: c#, xnet, httpwebrequest

Доброго времени суток, помогите решить проблему : при попытке сделать запрос на сайт sscasino.online дает ошибку `xNet.HttpException" в xNet.dll ("Не удалось установить SSL-соединение с HTTP-сервером 'sscasino.online'.") xNet.HttpException` (xNET)

и

`System.Net.WebException" в System.dll ("Базовое соединение закрыто: Непредвиденная ошибка при передаче.") System.Net.WebException` (WebRequest)

```
request.UserAgent = useragent;
request.IgnoreProtocolErrors = true;
request.SslCertificateValidatorCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

var result = request.Get(link);
```

и

```
  WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(Url);
  WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
  Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
  StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
  string Out = sr.ReadToEnd();
  sr.Close();
```

При этом, если включить http debbuger pro, то запросы идут нормально. Тестил на 
 нескольких машинах

Comment: Дак а вы чего хотите сделать то, просто обратиться к главной странице и получить ее контент?

Comment: @sp7 для начала просто гет запрос, а потом и пост. Проблема в том, что при гет запросе получаю ошибку "Не удалось установить SSL-соединение с HTTP-сервером 'sscasino.online'." Хотя с браузера грузится нормально

Comment: @sp7 есть идеи ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xNet` не будет работать из коробки:

- `xNet` основан на `SslStream` и использует протокол по умолчанию: `sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(address.Host);` [xNet GitHub](https://github.com/X-rus/xNet/blob/master/xNet/%7EHttp/HttpRequest.cs)
- протокол `SslStream`у должен быть уcтановлен так:
  `sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(address.Host, null, SslProtocols.Tls12, true);` [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145061(v=vs.110).aspx)

Два варианта:

- внести вклад в GitHub xNet с изменением выше
- cкомпилировать xNet локально с изменением выше

ТАКЖЕ:

Можно попытаться установить протокол по умолчанию где-нибудь вначале (Global.asax -> Startup если есть):

`System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`

или

`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= (SecurityProtocolType)3072;`

Я не пытался проверить, работает ли этот последний вариант

Comment: спасибо, наиболее исчерпывающий ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Для `WebRequest` надо было добавить строку  `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`
Для `xNet` так и не разобрался

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы получить контент страницы можно воспользоваться классом `HttpClient` из библиотеки [Microsoft HTTP Client Libraries](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/):

```
private static async Task<string> GetContentFromPageAsync(string page)
{
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = 
            SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | 
            SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | 
            SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    using (var response = await client.GetAsync(page))
    using (var content = response.Content)
    {
         var result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
         return result;
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var content = GetContentFromPageAsync("https://sscasino.online/").Result;
    Console.WriteLine(content);
}
```

---

```
// Создаем прокси.
var proxyUri = string.Format("{0}:{1}", proxyServerAddress, proxyServerPort);
var proxyCredential = new NetworkCredential(proxyUserName, proxyUserPassword);

var proxy = new WebProxy(proxyUri, false)
{
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = proxyCredential
};

// Создаем ClientHandler.
HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
{
    Proxy = proxy,
    PreAuthenticate = true,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
};

var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
```

Comment: угу, вроде работает, а можете проверить, правильно ли я сделал передачу кукисов 
[ссылка](http://www.note-pad.net/ru/secretlink/8d190b3aca453cd26e2c2b668b12f327?page=2)

Comment: Похоже на правду, только я не вижу что бы вы где-нибудь добавляли куку в контейнер.

Comment: хм, включил proxifier, настроил на ру проксю (мне перед этим запросом надо другие послать, а они только с ру принимают), а когда дело доходит до этого запроса (GetContentFromPageAsync), то дает ошибку в строке using (var response = await client.GetAsync(page)) текст ошибки : Произошла ошибка при отправке запроса. При этом xnet работает нормально (при условии, что включен http debbuger). С браузера все норм, стандартный WebRequest тоже слег с этой ошибкой, чет не пойму ничего

Comment: Если быть точным, то WebRequest  дает ошибку "базовое соединение закрыто.. " в строке HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse(); . Хотелось бы починить xNet он из всех более-менее адекватный, но почемут работает только с http debbuger

Comment: Дак вы `HttpClient` использует через прокси?

Comment: я всю систему через прокси провел. Можно ли как-то все таки xNet сделать ?

Comment: Если вы используете прокси, это отдельно придется сконфигурировать. `Можно ли как-то все таки xNet сделать ?` может и можно, никогда не работал с данной библиотекой. А чем вам не угодил `HttpClient`?

Comment: мне с xNet удобнее, нету таких заморочек, как с другими либами, все удобно используется, вот единственное - это ошибка ssl, хотелось бы именно xNet. 
Вообще, я делаю несколько запросов с разными сайтами и нужно все время передавать куки, прокси и тп это очень неудобно реализовано в HttpClient и WebRequest

Comment: "сли вы используете прокси, это отдельно придется сконфигурировать"

можете привести пример с проксями ?

Comment: Привести смогу, единственное, что мне не проверить работоспособность будет, т.к. на моем ПК прокси не используется.

Comment: Приведите, я потестю

Answer (score 0):

Протоколы HTTP через SSL используют правильно выданный сертификат для проверки.
Можно исползовать делегат `RemoteCertificateValidationCallback` для проверки SSL-сертификата.

```
public static void ConnSSL()
{
 WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(Url);
request.Proxy = null;
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
//Проверяет  SSL-сертификаты
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new  System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
      return true;
}
```

Дополнительная информация о [RemoteCertificateValidationCallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.remotecertificatevalidationcallback(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
{
     HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest) base.GetWebRequest(uri);
     webRequest.KeepAlive = false;
     return webRequest;
}
```

[ссылка GetWebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21728897/7198805)

Comment: Дает ошибку в строке` HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();  Базовое соединение закрыто: Непредвиденная ошибка при передаче.`

Comment: ответ обновлен и  читайте ссылка которые добовлено

Comment: Гхм, о какой проверке ValidateServerCertificate идёт речь, если у вас там стоит заглушка `return true`?! Очень нехорошо рекомендовать использовать подобный код!